# Getting error "Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(E:\Mozilla\firefox.exe) on port 7055"

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using firefox version 23.0.1 and selenium 2.35.0 jar. when i try to run the scripts , all scripts are failed with the error message saying "Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(E:\Mozilla\firefox.exe) on port 7055" . please help me out to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Manasa.

Comment: Sounds like version compatibility to me. Can you show us a screenshot of the Firefox help window? It'll show the exact version.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could occur if your Firefox executable is not located in that location.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","PATH_TO_FIREFOX_HERE");
```

This code will update the location of Firefox in the system properties.  In the event that this doesn't work, check to make sure the port is open on your computer by using netstat or a similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the more appropriate answer for you boot bootstrap in your code -

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();   
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("C:\\path to firefox\\firefox.exe"));   
driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);
```

Hope, it helps !

Regards,
[Anand Chavan](http://www.anandc.me)

Comment: Did you mentioned correct path ?  

If Yes -  

Please try executing your IDE with "Run As Administrator" option.